# Mysql - Fetch 5 rows above and under user (ranking)

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have a table:

```
r_user  | r_points |
--------------------
user1   | 12       |
user2   | 124      |
user3   | 34       |
user4   | 35       |
user5   | 57       |
user6   | 3        |
user7   | 452      |
user8   | 8        |
user9   | 12       |
user-c  | 0        |
user-b  | 0        |
user-a  | 0        |
```

Lets say I want to fetch the ranking for **user6**. I want 5 users above and below his entry ordered by r_points and next r_user ASC, so that users with equal points ( user-c, user-b, user-a ) are sorted ASC like ( user-a, user-b... ).

If there aren't 5 users above or underneath, the difference should be put to the opposite. So if **user6** is 4 from bottom, I want 6 users fetched above. Always a count of 10 users.

That is my result, I would like to have:

```
r_user  | r_points |
--------------------
user5   | 57       |
user4   | 35       |
user3   | 34       |
user9   | 12       |
user1   | 12       | -> In this direction ORDER is other way round
user8   | 8        |
user6   | 3        | --> THATS THE USER BY ID <--
user-a  | 0        |
user-b  | 0        |
user-c  | 0        |
```

I have no idea, how to do that, since my table has r_user as PK and no AI-ID.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

That's my version of it. However that version is not fetching more users above/below if the user is on 3rd from bottom. That only works if there are 5 rows underneath and above. That's not what I want.

```
(
SELECT r_user, r_points
FROM ranking 
WHERE r_points >= ( SELECT r_points FROM ranking WHERE r_user = 'user6' )
ORDER BY r_points ASC LIMIT 5
)
UNION DISTINCT
(
SELECT r_user, r_points
FROM ranking 
WHERE r_points <= ( SELECT r_points FROM ranking WHERE r_user = 'user6' )
ORDER BY r_points DESC LIMIT 6
)
ORDER BY r_points DESC, r_user ASC
```

Comment: so you need 10 records or just to order the table?

Comment: 10 records, because table could be of 10000 rows. To much to display.

Comment: I would query nine above and nine below, then have your client clip the range.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you have no unique `id`, so in my fiddle the user is hard coded by this line `IF(t.r_user = 'user2'`. To change user you have to change that value.

Hope this will be helpful to you:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2329/31

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    t.*,
    IF(@idx IS NULL, @idx:=1, @idx:=@idx+1) idx,
    IF(t.r_user = 'user2',@median:=r_points, IF(@start IS NULL, @start:=@idx, IF(@after IS NULL, @start:=@idx, null))),
    IF(@median IS NULL, IF(@before IS NULL,@before:=1, @before:=@before+1) ,
    IF(@after IS NULL ,@after:=0, @after:=@after+1)) 

  FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    ORDER BY r_points DESC
    ) t
  ) t2
 WHERE IF(1+@before+@after<=10, true,
          IF(@before<=5, t2.idx >= 0 AND t2.idx <= @start+5+(5-@before),
             IF(@after<=4, t2.idx >= @start-4-(4-@after),
                t2.idx >= @start-4 AND t2.idx <= @start+5
             )
          )
        );
```